# A webview app gets permissions granted but crashes whenever you use them

Tags: java, android, webview, permissions, crash

I'm currently working on a webview app in Android Studio but I'm a web developer and certainly a bit lost. This app needs to have access to camera, location phone calls and other features, so after researching I managed to declare and ask for them via pop-ups, but even though the user grants them, the app will crash whenever you tap on the buttons for camera or phone calling, and I cannot figure out what or where the problem is. This does not happen in pc browser or even phone browser.

First of all i learned that permissions need to be declared in AndroidManifest.xml and so I wrote them down. Then I read that I had to write te functions to actually ask for those permissions, and after a few days searching, I could only find one method I understood, but this way the user gets prompted with all the pop-ups at the start of the execution.
This at least worked because I was able to check the app info and confirm it, but after all of this, whenever one of the buttons that perform the action is pressed the whole app crashes and now I'm not sure what to do.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml where I declared permissions:

```xml
    <!-- Internet --> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- Storage--> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  
    <!-- Camera-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <!-- Location-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Phone-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <!-- Calendar--> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <!-- Contacts--> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- SMS--> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
```

Then this is what I did on MainActivity.java first my onCreate method:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Código agregado
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        // Activamos jаvascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // Activamos el LocalStorage
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        // Activamos el focus tactil
        mWebView.setFocusable(true);
        mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        // Configuraciones varias
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        // Url que carga la app (webview)
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://reclamador.globalten.es");
        // Forzamos el webview para que abra los enlaces internos dentro de la la APP
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        // Forzamos el webview para que abra los enlaces externos en el navegador
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
        // Permite inspeccionar el codigo a traves de chrome
        mWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        // Fin del código agregado

        // Código añadido
        int Permission_All = 1;

        String[] Permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if(!hasPermissions(this, Permissions)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, Permissions, Permission_All);
        }
        // Fin del código añadido
    }
```

Then the method to check if they have already been granted:

```java
// Codigo añadido
    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context!=null && permissions!=null){
            for(String permission: permissions){
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    // Fin del código añadido
```

As I said, this is a webApp so I don't know how to connect the buttons with the pop-ups, every tutorial I saw shows you how to create a button on AndroidStudio, but in my case its a web full developed.
The phone call button inside the web is an  tag
There is another for the mail  but I did not see any permission related for this case
And there are some inputs for gallery pictures or using the camera that dont work either, I am just finished student of web development so don't be too harsh on me and thank you for your time and help!

## EDIT

I managed to solve both tel: and mailto: issues by changing the method inside MyAppWebViewClient class (MyAppWebViewClient.java) from

```java
// Código agregado
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // Url base de la APP (al salir de esta url, abre el navegador) poner como se muestra, sin https://
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("reclamador.globalten.es")) {
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
// Fin del código agregado*/
```

To this one:

```java
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:") || url.startsWith("market:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I only have the issue with the file inpunts that can access the gallery or take a picture to upload, so any further advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Crashes typically created crash logs / exceptions + stack traces, show them!

Comment: Just a FYI if you are planning on releasing on the Google Play store: READ_SMS and SEND_SMS aren't allowed to be used anymore if you are not registering your app as default SMS handler. This of course doesn't apply if you don't plan to publish on the play store. If possible you should reduce the amount of permissions (if not required) nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply @Ch4t4r! I was thinking the same, also for what I've seen this app does not need contact permissions at all... I will check those right away!